# How to hide UITextField, UILabel, UIButton on ViewDidLoad method?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

I am trying to hide my texts labels and buttons

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide us more information. Your description is quite poor, and we won't be able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the hidden property of `UIView` (`UITextField`, `UILabel` and `UIButton` are all subclasses of `UIView`).

```
myControl.hidden = YES;
```

Comment: I did try it. But its not hiding them when the app loads!

Answer (score 1):

1. go to the .h File for the view controller and make an IBOutlet with the data type appropriate for your control UITextView, UILabel, etc...
2. go to the interface builder and bind the IBOutlet you declared to the item you want.
3. Use `myControl.hidden = YES;`

Please do not hesitate to ask for clarifications for any of these steps.

Comment: Hi Mr. Fayez, thanks for the reply. I did synthesize and bind them to appropriate outletes. But in .h file, I am putting the controls as @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *userName; Its not working!